# Develop multiple versions parallel with git-flow

Tags: git, git-flow

i know this has been asked so much times, i couldn't find appropriate solution to my problem.

in my project, we can work on 3 version parallel. lets say 1.0, 2.0, 3.0. so version.
i will focus my question on the branching and merging from dev and back.
each version should not contain features from greater versions, and by merging back and forked from dev thats make a problem.

i had this idea where we have multiple dev branches, that will run our `CI` pipline for each commit merged into branch starts with `"dev"`. this way, the `dev-X` branch wont merged into `dev` (main) until the previous version has completed. that gives the flexibility for many versions, and maintain safety.

[image]

feedback would be much appreciated
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a use case for **support branches** as described by [gitversion](https://gitversion.net/docs/learn/branching-strategies/gitflow/examples#support-branches) to me.